# How to filter SQL query results that id would be in a range

Tags: sql

I need IDs to be either divisions of 100 or next 99. Like

```
id
0
99
100
199
200
299
```

How to filter the select by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
where mod(id, 100) in (0, 99)
```

or:

```
where (id % 100) in (0, 99)
```

or:

```
where id mod 100 in (0, 99)
```

The specific syntax depends on your database.

Comment: For those that  `mod(id, 100) in (0, 99)` or  `(id % 100) in (0, 99)` don't work, try `id mod 100 in (0, 99)`

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where id like any ('0', '%00', '%99')
```

Comment: . . You should specify the *1* database that supports `like any`.

Comment: According to SO rules, shouldn't you have edited my post to improve it? I find wierd you ignore guidelines with these 800k reputation, were you trying to say something between the lines?